# Restart IIS / Recycle App Pool after X num of errors?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

My company is plagued by the infamous "[Hashtable insert failed. Load factor too high](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505322/hashtable-insert-failed-load-factor-too-high-asp-net-2-0)" error on our webfarm [6 Server 2003 SP2 boxes w/IIS 6.0].  I realize that there is a kb update that will resolve this error (see link), however others in the department are not contacting Microsoft in a timely fashion (and I don't have the authority to do so).  We have found that either a full-blown iisreset or recycling the App Pool clears the issues.

Is there a way we could configure IIS to monitor the number of errors it is generating and recycle and/or reset after a certain threshold has been reached?  It should be pretty easy to tell - we get literally 1,000+ errors per min. on the affected server when this error is tripped.

Answer (score 1):

If you could [catch the error](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/errorhandling.aspx) (which it sounds like you could) in the app, you could get the app to recycle itself. See http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/5688.aspx for details on how to do this.

Of course you need to be aware of the issues with doing this.

Alternatively you could get [app pool recycling working](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1eee28e2-b319-4b4e-8267-a8c0aa0dcf36.mspx?mfr=true) for the following criteria:

- After elapsed time.
- After X requests.
- At a scheduled time.
- After using a set amount of memory.

Perhaps you could find one of those criteria that help?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small monitor application to check perfmon and execute the command to recycle the application pool when a threshold is hit (I believe there is a WMI interface that could restart a single application pool)

not a fantastic solution I'll admit...