# HashTable Insert Failed. Load Factor Too High. .NET 2.0 SP2

Tags: .net, hashtable

We've just encountered this error on our web app, and immediately found the article here [Hashtable insert failed. Load factor too high. - ASP.NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505322/hashtable-insert-failed-load-factor-too-high-asp-net-2-0).

However, the hotfix that this points to (http://support.microsoft.com/?id=927579) was already included in .NET 2.0 SP1 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945757).

A restart of the WWW Publishing Service made it go away. Does anyone know of any other valid conditions where this can occur? And how to make sure they don't happen?

Thanks.

Edit: I believe this could also be linked to another issue we're having with a Dictionary object stored in the Application scope.  I've changed the code to use Application.Lock()/Unlock() around writes to the Dictionary, so we'll see if this reoccurs after these changes are released.

Any more pointers anyone could give on possible reasons beyond simply a framework bug would be highly rewarded with praise and adulation!

Comment: Is it possible that the Hashtable you're using genuinely does have a load factor that's too high? It may be that you need to improve your hash function so that it is more unique, reducing the chance of collisions.

Comment: Maybe... In that case I suppose my question relates more to what exactly could cause this exception! All related Google searches point to Framework bugs and generally end up at the above hotfix, but most articles I've found are 2007 and earlier.

Comment: Unless you have a hashtable of a few million or more entries, I cant see how this can happen. In that case you should really be using a DB...

Comment: Cheers Leppie, that's my thought exactly.  Unfortunately I only have a report of this issue occurring and don't have a stack trace from it, but it happened on every single page in the app until IIS was restarted, which points to either (a) our user session verification (as per my Application-level Dictionary edit above) or (b) something else entirely!  The dictionary will never really contain more than 1000 entries so i can't see it being that, and I'm fairly sure we'd get a Dictionary-related exception rather than a HashTable exception in that case anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, there's a hotfix for 2.0 SP2 and 3.5 SP1 that may resolve the issue: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB968432

I should add that the first problem appears to have been resolved by the inclusion of Application.Lock()/Unlock() as mentioned in my original post (it's a tough one to test though as it's totally random!).  A subsequent "Hashtable insert failed" error occurred on ReflectGetAttributes() as per the article, which is what the hotfix is purported to address.