# How to prevent WCF Service call System.InvalidOperationException: Hashtable insert failed. Load factor too high

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, .net-3.5, wcf-client

We have a multi-threaded queue processing service that has started getting the error below. This service has run without any issues for a long time. I am unaware of any updates that have been applied to IIS or windows.

I've [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505322/hashtable-insert-failed-load-factor-too-high-asp-net-2-0) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114395/hashtable-insert-failed-load-factor-too-high-asp-net-4-0-mvc3) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888072/hashtable-insert-failed-load-factor-too-high-net-2-0-sp2) that lead to the same error, but they don't seem to be on the same scenario (WCF Client, .NET 3.5). The closest I've come to [a solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toddca/archive/2007/01/26/hashtable-insert-failed-load-factor-too-high.aspx) is to phone Microsoft support, but I can't get through and have tried for a while. Is there any alternative solutions?

Note: I know this should be a windows service and not an IIS Web Service but it works and I'm not allowed to change it.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'ServiceReference1.TimePeriodABIEType'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Hashtable insert failed. Load factor too high.
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.DynamicAssemblies.IsTypeDynamic(Type type)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.ImportTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo, Boolean directReference)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo source, Boolean directReference, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.ModelScope.GetTypeModel(Type type, Boolean directReference)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.IncludeType(Type type, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.IncludeTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.IncludeType(Type type, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.OperationReflector.EnsureMessageInfos()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.EnsureMessageInfos()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.CreateFormatter()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IOperationBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription description, ClientOperation proxy)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BindOperations(ContractDescription contract, ClientRuntime proxy, DispatchRuntime dispatch)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildProxyBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, BindingParameterCollection& parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.BuildChannelFactory(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnOpening()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.Open()
```

Comment: This looks like a race condition in IsTypeDynamic(Type type). It uses the hash table without synchronization. Report it on Connect.

Comment: I wouldn't be allowed to send the code that causes this error due to strict security protocols.

Comment: I have this same issue with .Net 4.0. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Harindaka Unfortunately not, it just went away after a couple of days and I've not been able to reproduce it.

Comment: Installing the below hotfix fixed it for me. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2733944/en-us