# 'Failed to insert into hash table. Load factor too high' Why this error only Google Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hash, hashtable

I have a problem when I load the page.
I get this error 'Failed to insert into the hash table. Load factor too high'. 
I get this error only in Google Chrome.

In Internet Explorer and Mozilla, it all works ok. 
Why does it only fail for Google Chrome?

Comment: Which .net version you are using

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888072/hashtable-insert-failed-load-factor-too-high-net-2-0-sp2

Comment: i've using .net 4.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HashTable Insert Failed. Load Factor Too High. .NET 2.0 SP2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888072/hashtable-insert-failed-load-factor-too-high-net-2-0-sp2)